# Find if checkbox is cheked in tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have problem with determining if checkbox is checked in parent tr. If checkbox is cheked this tr shoud be skiped. It seemed like everything is correct in my code,but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#MainContent_gvOrders > tbody > tr > td .col1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).closest('tr').has('input:not(:checked)')) {
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());
        }
    });
    $('#tp').html(sum);
});

function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#MainContent_gvOrders > tbody > tr > td .col1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).closest('tr').has('input:not(:checked)')) {
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());
        }
    });
    $('#tp').html(sum);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us your HTML, but this should work fine. What's the problem? Is `sum` 0? Is `sum` all of them together? Does your computer burn when you run the JS?

Comment: FYI, always mention radix when dealing with parseInt. like this: `parseInt($(this).text(), 10);`.

Comment: Problem is that value of tr with cheked checkbox counting as well, but it's should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $('#MainContent_gvOrders  tr:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))').filter(function () {
                sum += parseInt($(this).find('td.col1').text(), 10);
                });
            $('#tp').html(sum);
        });
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            var sum = 0;
            $('#MainContent_gvOrders  tr:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))').filter(function () {
               sum += parseInt($(this).find('td.col1').text(), 10);
            });
            $('#tp').html(sum);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this using below code.

```
$('#MainContent_gvOrders  tr:has("input:not(:checked)")').filter(function(){
     return sum += parseInt($(this).find('td').text(), 10);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ers8F/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working  if ($('#MainContent_gvOrders  tr:has("input:not(:checked)")')) {
                    sum += parseInt($(this).text());
                }

Comment: You're right, but I forgot to mention that checkbox and values that I counting are in the same tr, in your example they are in different rows.

Comment: Now it looks like that (but still not working): $(document).ready(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $('#MainContent_gvOrders  tr:has("input:not(:checked)") td.col1').filter(function(){
                    return sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
                });
            $('#tp').html(sum);
        });

Comment: @user924646 what do you mean by not working? does it still counts the checked checkbox? or what?

Comment: @user924646 share your html so i can give you perfect solution

Comment: Yes, it's till counting checked checkboxes.

Comment: @user924646 i am asking you too paste your html code into your question

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `$(this).closest('tr').has('input:not(:checked)')` with `$(this).closest('tr').has('input:not(:checked)')[0]`. (*added [0] at last*)

The problem is that jquery functions always return something (*object*). So, if you check `if(object)` it will be always true.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#MainContent_gvOrders > tbody > tr > td .col1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).closest('tr').has('input:not(:checked)')[0]) {
            sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        }
    });
    $('#tp').html(sum);
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you can check the .length property on the returned object.

Comment: @rlemon yeah I was checking this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31044/1577396) and accidentally got this post.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is HTML:

```
    <div>
    <table class="bordered striped hovered" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_gvOrders" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Заказ</th><th scope="col">Pax</th><th scope="col">Child</th><th scope="col">PickUpTime</th><th scope="col">Скидка</th><th scope="col">Продал</th><th scope="col">Транспорт</th><th scope="col">Отмен</th><th scope="col">Причина</th><th scope="col">WhenSold</th><th scope="col">Price</th><th scope="col">Net</th><th scope="col">PriceChd</th><th scope="col">NetChd</th><th scope="col">TotalPrice</th><th scope="col">TotalNet</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input type="image" src="../img/edit.png" alt="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvOrders&#39;,&#39;Edit$0&#39;);return false;" /></td><td>Aphrodita VIP 03 Sep 2013</td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label4_0">1</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label5_0">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label11_0"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label12_0">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label1_0">Igor</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label13_0">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input id="MainContent_gvOrders_cbCancel_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvOrders$ctl02$cbCancel" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label14_0"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label6_0"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label7_0">800</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label8_0">380</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label9_0">600</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label10_0">350</span>
                </td><td class="col1">
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label2_0" class="col1">800</span>
                </td><td class="col2">
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label3_0" class="col2">380</span>
                </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input type="image" src="../img/edit.png" alt="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvOrders&#39;,&#39;Edit$1&#39;);return false;" /></td><td>Flying Hanuman (B) 02 Sep 2013</td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label4_1">1</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label5_1">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label11_1"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label12_1">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label1_1">Igor</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label13_1">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input id="MainContent_gvOrders_cbCancel_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvOrders$ctl03$cbCancel" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label14_1"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label6_1"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label7_1">3250</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label8_1">2200</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label9_1">3250</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label10_1">2200</span>
                </td><td class="col1">
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label2_1" class="col1">3250</span>
                </td><td class="col2">
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label3_1" class="col2">2200</span>
                </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input type="image" src="../img/edit.png" alt="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvOrders&#39;,&#39;Edit$2&#39;);return false;" /></td><td>Khao Lak 05 Sep 2013</td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label4_2">1</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label5_2">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label11_2">7:15</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label12_2">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label1_2">Igor</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label13_2">0</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span class="aspNetDisabled"><input id="MainContent_gvOrders_cbCancel_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvOrders$ctl04$cbCancel" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label14_2"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label6_2"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label7_2">2700</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label8_2">1500</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label9_2">1800</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label10_2">1300</span>
                </td><td class="col1">
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label2_2" class="col1">2700</span>
                </td><td class="col2">
                    <span id="MainContent_gvOrders_Label3_2" class="col2">1500</span>
                </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>
                    <span id="tp"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="tn"></span>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This markup generted by asp.net gridview control.

Comment: so here is what i understand....you want to sum the span text if checkbox inside first td is not checked...right.?

Comment: Well. we have tr with few td. We need last two, that contain total price and total net. In footer we have span #tp and #tn that should contain subtotal of the columns with .col1 and .col2. But I would like to skip tr that contains checked input. In this html it's first tr with checked input. Because I need td that contain class, I did modified your code a bit as follow: sum += parseInt($(this).find('td.col2').text(), 10);

Comment: Beuatiful solution! Thanks @Dipesh Parmar!